# Nested IF Formula is way too long

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a nested IF formula that I am trying to use for work. The limit is 255 characters and I have over 3500 characters in the formula, is there any way to make this work. Here is the base formula idea since I cannot disclose the actual values.

```
IF(CELL#=IPCODE, "item desc", IF(CELL#=IPCODE, "item desc", DNE))
```

The idea is that when the cell above has a specific number code, then it will return the description for the number. There are 86 number codes and item descriptions, what would be the best way to get this formula to work.

Comment: Sounds like VLOOKUP would be a better option.  What does your sheet look like?

Comment: If your formula is 3500 bytes long you might doing it wrong.  However, the answer is to write a either vlookup or macro in vbscript which has no such limitations.  Then call the macro from the cell.  Excel has built-in support for macros.

Comment: Excel has a limit of 255 characters for a single formula. If your nested IF formula exceeds this limit, you will need to find an alternative solution. One option is to split the formula into multiple cells and use cell references to create the nested IF statements. Another option is to use a lookup table to match the cell value with the corresponding item description.

Comment: For example, you could create a table with two columns: one for the cell value and one for the item description. Then you could use the VLOOKUP function to retrieve the item description based on the cell value. This would be much simpler and more efficient than a nested IF formula with 86 conditions.

Comment: @le nin had u tried this -> https://exceljet.net/functions/xlookup-function ?